# Java - Japanese filenames garbled

Tags: java, character-encoding, filenames, non-ascii-characters, cjk

I am running a standalone java process which writes data to multiple xlsx files in a parent target directory and upon completion, the entire target directory is zipped and uploaded to cloud and a download link is provided to the user. The xlsx file names and the name of the zip file is user defined and not possible to change.

The issue is with the names of the xlsx files created. If the filename selected by the user is Japanese, like

> サイン色紙プレゼントCPN_第2.xlsx

the corresponding file that is created in the system is of the form:

> ??????????CPN_?2?.xlsx

The same files are being uploaded to cloud and user is seeing garbled file names. However, the Japanese name of the zip file is not garbled and is in Japanese only.

Following is the code sample for creating xlsx files:

```
String fileName = userGivenName + "_" + randomUUID + ".xlsx";
File file = new File(tmpParentDirectoryName, fileName);

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
workbook.write(outputStream);
```

In this case the absolute path of the xlsx file created is like :

> /tmpDirectoryPath/??????????CPN_?2?_0c6b37ee-97c4-44d4-b80d-dfe5eafe0045.xlsx

Just like above there are multiple xlsx files created in the same *tmpDirectory*

Upon completion following is the code sample to create zip files and upload to cloud:

```
File[] files = getFilesInFolder(tmpDirectory);
if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
        continue;
}

File zipFile = new File(targetDirectory, compressedFileName);
createZipFile(files, zipFile);
String url = uploadFile(compressedFileName, zipFile);
```

Following piece of code writes data to zip file:

```
public static void createZipFile(File[] files, File zipFile) {
    if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(files)) {
        return;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));

    try {
        for (File file : files) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            try {
                String fileName = URLDecoder.decode(file.getName(), "UTF-8");
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
                zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zos.closeEntry();
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(fis);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(zos);
    }
}
```

The uploaded zip file has the correct Japanese name but the zip entries of the zip file have garbled xlsx filenames.

The standalone java process has following encoding options:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

Following is the output of the locale command:

```
locale
LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Can someone direct me as to what am I doing wrong here ? I want the same filenames to be uploaded as given by the user.

Comment: Did you check your user input Japanese filenames are encoded in UTF-8? If it is encoded in another encoding such like Shift-JIS, saving it as UTF-8 easily makes garbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to crack this.
The issue was with the system properties of the mesos slave that was executing the java process.
The process on the slave was started by a mesos master scheduler using a startup script. Due to this the default java locale properties were not being set up properly on the slave.

I added the following line to the start-up script of the slave:

```
export LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
```

Upon explicitly adding the locale property to the start-up script, was able to resolve the issue.